# UITextview in a UIScrollview paging

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview, uipagecontrol

I have been following a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) for paging through images within a `UIScrollview`.

The paging with `UIScrollview` section.

I now want to change this so instead of an `UIimageview`, it displays a `UITextview`. With different text as it is paged.

Not sure as to how to implement the textview instead of the imageview.

any ideas?

Thanks

code being used:

```
- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page {
    if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count) {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return;
    }

    // 1
    UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull*)pageView == [NSNull null]) {
        // 2
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0.0f;

        //UITextView *theTextView;
        theTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
        theTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        theTextView.editable = NO;

        theTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a very long text"];

           // 3
        //UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:page]];
        theTextView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        theTextView.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:theTextView];
        // 4
        [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:theTextView];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They are both `UIView` subclasses. It should work the exact same way. Simply deactivate `allowUserInteraction` on the `UITextViews` if you don't want them to scroll and the `UIScrollView` should scroll the exact same way as if it was filled with `UIImageViews`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd add the UITextView the exact same way you'd add a UIImageView. Initialize a UITextView, set up any properties you want on it, and add it to the UIScrollView as a subview. So where ever you're adding UIImageViews, replace that code with something like this:

```
self.theTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
self.theTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
self.theTextView.editable = NO;
... //however else you want to modify your UITextView

[self.theScrollView addSubview:self.theTextView];
```

Comment: ive just tried that but all i get displayed is a blank textview and no paging occurring